# How can I generate TPC-DS queries for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, benchmark

I'm using TPC-DS to run some benchmarks on a few versions of postgres that I have. I noticed that there is no template for generating the TPC-DS queries with the target database as postgres. The `query_templates` directory contains template files for `ansi`, `sqlserver`, `db2`, `oracle`, and `netezza`, but none for postgres.

I've tried running the queries generated by each of the previously listed targets on postgres, but they all seem to have some kind of syntax that postgres doesn't support, because most of them fail to run.

Is it possible to generate these TPC-DS queries for postgres? Or is there a `postgres.tpl` file that can be downloaded somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the TPC-DS, but I know that [HammerDB](http://hammerora.sourceforge.net/) will perform a TPC-H(ad hoc DSS) benchmark test against PostgreSQL.  If you're looking for a benchmark, but not specifically a TPC-DS, this is a good tool for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have already run a bunch of TPCH benchmarks on my postgres databases. I specifically need to use TPC-DS because of its high-volume and high-CPU/IO load.

Answer (score 0):

Util HammerDB has addon Autohamer which can create TPC-DS tests, you can check this link http://hammerora.sourceforge.net/Autohammer/content/ch01.html